# Python Password Hashing with hashlib

Tags: python, hash, hashlib, login-system

I'm trying to hash a password for a login system I am creating. I am using the hashlib import and using the blake2b hash algorithm. I can't seem to figure out how to hash a variable such as **passwordEntry**. All the hashlib examples are just of blake2b hashing characters. For example: **blake2b(b'IWantToHashThis')** I am quite confused on why the "b" letter has to be included in the hash. If I try to hash a variable the "b" letter can't be concluded with the variable I want to hash. Example of me trying to hash a variable: **blake2b(passwordEntry)** Another example of me trying to hash the variable: **blake2b(b passwordEntry)** On the second example I just gave hashlib thinks that it is trying to hash the variable "b passwordEntry." Like I said before the "b" letter has to be included in the hashing algorithm for it to preform correctly. *Sorry for the long question if it is hard to follow I understand*.

Comment: `b"Some data"` stands for raw binary data and not text data. you will need to `yourText.encode('utf-8')` to convert text to binary data. and then it comes to this: `blake2b(passwordEntry.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()` and it should return what you want

Comment: Encryption functions work with *bytes*. If you do `passwordEntry = "IWantToHashThis"` then `passwordEntry` is a string. To convert it to the equivalent `bytes` object, encode it as UTF-8: `blake2b(passwordEntry.encode("UTF-8")`.

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.blake2b) for `hashlib.blake2b`. This function requires a [bytes-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object) as the argument.

Comment: @BoarGules `UTF-8` should be quoted as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The letter `b` only works before quotes, [`"`, `'`, `"""`, `''''`].
And it is there to notate that this string is `bytes`.
If you want to convert your string to bytes you can do that by
`b"string"` or `"string".encode()`. However, in your case you can only use the `encode()` method of `str` since `b` only works for Literal Strings.
So in your case it will be `blake2b(passwordEntry.encode())`

Comment: What do you mean? it does. Please be more specific

Comment: **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'** That's the error.

Comment: That has nothing to do with my answer, That is because your `passwordEntry` is `None` and you got to check out why, you surely have done something wrong if you get the password as None [in addition to the question above, `b passwordEntry`]

Comment: Okay, thank you for this information. I will try and look for the problem.